# jquery how to count rows in several tables

Tags: jquery

I know how to count rows in a single table (and display the result) but how to deal with several tables? (Table ids are dynamically created)

```html
<table is="myTable1"><tr><td>RowCount: <span class="rowsC"></span></td></tr><tr><td>Row 1</td></tr></table>
<table id="myTable2"><tr><td>RowCount: <span class="rowsC"></span></td></tr><tr><td>Row 1</td></tr><tr><td>Row 2</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```js
const tables = document.querySelectorAll('table');

const rowCount = [...tables].map(table => {
  const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr').length;
  const rowsC = table.querySelector('.rowsC');
  
  rowsC.innerHTML = `Row Count: ${rows}`;
})
```

```html
<table is="myTable1"><tr><td>RowCount: <span class="rowsC"></span></td></tr><tr><td>Row 1</td></tr></table>
<table id="myTable2"><tr><td>RowCount: <span class="rowsC"></span></td></tr><tr><td>Row 1</td></tr><tr><td>Row 2</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I want the result for each table displayed in the table. In a further step i would like to additionally count table rows with specific classes. And the counter should update if the DOM has changed (table rows are dragable). 

```html
<table id="myTable1"><tr><td>Rows total count: <span class="rowstotalC"></span> myClass Rows count: <span class="myClassrowsC"></span></td></tr><tr class="myClass"><td>Row 1</td></tr><tr class="myClass"><td>Row 2</td></tr><tr"><td>Row 3</td></tr></table>```

Comment: You can use my logic and put a class of "total-count" or something in each table and as you're iterating through each table do something like document.querySelector(".totalCount").innerHTML = "total count: " + rowCount; or something along those lines.

Comment: again, thank you for your reply! but its not exactly what i need. the result for each table has to be displayed within the table.

Comment: That's exactly what my last comment does.